# Wallpaper zooms in my phone only

Tags: android, zooming, android-wallpaper

I'm trying to make an app which picks image from drawable and sets it as a wallpaper. Its working fine with other phones like Galaxy and Infinix but when I set it on my own Huawei phone, the wallpaper zooms in.

```
   public void setWallpaper(View view) throws IOException {

    Bitmap bmp1=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    Bitmap bmp2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp1, width, height, true);
    wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
    wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
    try {
        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bmp2);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wallpaper set",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }
   catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: May be, the image resolution is smaller than your phone resolution.

Comment: How can i solve that ?

Comment: use 1080*1920 image resolution, images in your app.